# MatLab Optimize Matrix-wise Element Comparison

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization

I am currently comparing elements of two matrices `A` and `B` in two nested for loops to create a new matrix `F` with the higher value at each position. All three matrices have equal dimensions.

My current code looks like this (MWE):

```
F = zeros(n, n)
Indeces_max_i = zeros(n, n)
for i=1 : max

    %generate the matrix, mock example
    B = randn(n, n) 

    for c=1 : size(F,1) %Loop over each element, possible to optimise?
        for l=1 : size(F,2)
             if B(c,l) > F(c,l)
                  F(c,l) = B(c,l);
                  Indeces_max_i(c,l) = i;
             end
        end
    end
end
```

As this can get quite computational heavy, I was wondering if there is a possibility to improve performance of the for loop 1 - and potentially if this solution could also apply if `B` had size `n x n x m` (so it would take the highest value of each element along dimensions `m`)?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `F = max(A,B)` ?

Comment: To get the indices `Indices_max = B > F`. Do this before `F = max(F,B)`

Comment: @obchardon Thanks so much! Indeed I was simply looking for max(A,B) but forgot that works with two (or more) matrices as well! Thanks for the suggestion as well JAC